# Data format for Spark ALS recommendation system with implicit feedback

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, recommendation-engine

The [ALS module](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#module-pyspark.ml.recommendation) in Spark assumes the data to be in form of `(user, product, rating)` tuples. When using `implicitPrefs=True` the ratings are assumed to be implicit ratings, so ratings equal to 0 have a special meaning and are not treated as unknown. As described by [Hu et al (2008)](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4781121/), the implicit ratings are used as weights by ALS. When using implicit ratings, the "missing" ratings [need to be passed directly to the algorithms as zeros](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251467/implicit-matrix-factorization-for-recommendations-are-ratings-0-required).

My question is: does ALS module needs user to provide the "missing" implicit ratings as zeros, or does it automatically populate the missing cells with zeros?

To give an example, say that I have three users, three products and their ratings (using `(user, product, rating)` format):

```
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 3)
(3, 1, 1)
(3, 3, 2)
```

So user 1 did not rate product 3, user 2 did not rate neither 1, nor 2, etc. **Can I pass this data directly to ALS?** Or maybe, do I have to expand it to all the 3*3 possible combinations, where unrated products have ratings populated with zeros, i.e.

```
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 3, 0)
(2, 1, 0)
(2, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 0)
(3, 1, 1)
(3, 2, 0)
(3, 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be considered as an answer.

**Of course you don't need to pass the missing ratings whether it's implicit or explicit.**

One of the strength of spark is computing your prediction matrix using sparse matrices representation.

If you wish to know a little bit more about sparse matrices, you can check the following link :

[What are sparse matrices used for ? What is its application in machine learning ?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-sparse-matrices-used-for-What-is-its-application-in-machine-learning)

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of the answer in that link.